# Strange log entries in apache access log that contain the server name

Tags: apache-2.2, http

In my apache access log I occasionally find entries that look like this:

```
63.186.66.22 - - [20/Feb/2014:00:00:03 +0100] "POST https://www.myserver.com:8080/some/path HTTP/1.1" 200 446 "-"
```

instead of

```
63.186.66.22 - - [20/Feb/2014:00:00:03 +0100] "POST /some/path HTTP/1.1" 200 446 "-"
```

Notice the superfluous https://www.myserver.com:8080 that seems to be present in the POST request (the port 8080 doesn't even make sense as my apache server is only listening on 80 and 443).

I've read up on the HTTP spec and found (as michael pointed out in the comment) that a complete URI is just as valid in a post request as an absolute path).

I'm still curious where the (wrong) port number might come from. Has anyone seen this happen with a specific http client (library)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `mod_proxy` loggging those lines.

Comment: Yes, this apache is being used as reverse proxy and the post request shown above are actually served via mod_proxy. But that does not explain why some log entries contain servername and port so I still think that it's some weird client's fault.

Comment: @sme Either format is valid in HTTP.